# Request different URL in single php page

Tags: php

I want to make 1 single php page to request different url like:

1. name.php?id=lee
2. name.php?id=john
3. name.php?id=miku

When i go to `www.example.com/name.php?id=lee`

It will show information about lee.

This will be done without database, all infos will be placed in the `name.php` file.

How this can be done in easy way?

Comment: if you do not have database then you can use php array to store user info.

Comment: You can use XML files as well, storing all your users there and updating the XML as you go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input will be in the variable named $_GET['id'].
Then you can just use a "switch" for this purpose: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_switch.asp

```
<?php
switch ($_GET['id']) {
  case "lee":
    echo "Hi Lee!";
    break;
  case "john":
    echo "Hello mr. John!";
    break;
  case "miku":
    echo "Buongiorno Miku!";
    break;
  default: // In all other cases
    echo "You're nobody";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($_GET['id'] == 'lee') {
    // Info about John
}
else if ($_GET['id'] == 'john') {
    // Info about John
}
// And so on..
```

OR you can use switch, case

```
switch ($_GET['id']) {
    case 'lee':
        // Info about Lee
    break;
    case 'john':
        // Info about John
    break;
}
```

Comment: a switch or an array lookup is much better in this usecase... to much overhead and code-complexity with if-else statements

Comment: I edited and put in a switch, case as you downvoted and commented. Gimme a chance!

Comment: I have removed the downvote... Doesnt have to do with giving a chance... Only with correct or incorrect answers ;)

Comment: Though my answer was still correct regardless of if there are better, or in this case preferred ways of achieving the same result ;)

Comment: Yes... I sort of used the wrong phrasing there... Not a native English speaker, sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

Even though I want to push you to a database... This should be the general tendancy:

```
$requestId = $_GET['id'];

$names = array(
    'lee' => array('name'=> 'lee'),
    'john' => array('name' => 'john'),
    'miku' => array('name' => 'miku'),
);

echo '<pre>'.print_r($names[$requestId], true).'</pre>';
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an associative `array` to statically store the information from the user and retrieve the proper user from the url using `$_GET`.

Example

```
$users = array(
    '0' => array(
        'name' => 'Jet',
        'surname' => 'Lee',
        // any other data relevant for you
    ),

    '1' => array(
        'name' => 'John',
        'surname' => 'Smith',
        // any other data relevant for you
    )
);

switch ($_GET['id']) {
    case "lee":
        // do something with the user lee
        break;
    case "john":
        // do something with the user john
        break;
    default:
        // fallback in case of a not recognized id
}
```

Anyway, consider storing your information somewhere, like an XML, JSON or CSV file, or even a plain text one.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

`www.example.com/name.php?id1=lee&id2=john&id3=miku`

To get the values:

```
$x = $_REQUEST['id1'];
$y = $_REQUEST['id2'];
$z = $_REQUEST['id3'];
```

Or why not use a database to store the values and retrieve it later.

Comment: I don't think this is what the question is about, however.